# JQuery sum using checkbox value and textbox value

Tags: javascript, jquery

How could I get the Final Total based on the sum of a checkbox value and the contents of a textbox?

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Bhuro/az1r9fdL/)

My HTML:

```
<table border="1">
<tr><td>10<input type="checkbox" class="tot_amount" value="10"></td><td>10<input id="os1" type="text"></td></tr>
<tr><td>20<input type="checkbox" class="tot_amount" value="20"></td><td>20<input id="os2" type="text" ></td></tr>
<tr><td>Total<input type="text" id="total1" readonly></td><td>Total2<input id="total2" type="text" readonly></td></tr>
</table>
Final Total<input type="text" id="final" readonly >
```

And Javascript:

```
$(".tot_amount").click(function(event) {
var total = 0;
$(".tot_amount:checked").each(function() {
total += parseInt($(this).val());
});

if (total == 0) {
$('#total1').val('');
}
else {
$('#total1').val(total);
}
});



$('#os1, #os2').on('input',function(){
var os1= parseFloat($('#os1').val()) || 0;
var os2= parseFloat($('#os2').val()) || 0;

$('#total2').val(os1 + os2); 

});
```

Comment: Can You Stop It! That's Really BORING!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32906278/get-response-use-then-problems#comment-53640932

Comment: It"s Change Contain..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just bind a focus event and do it -

```
$('#final').bind('focus',function(){
    $(this).val(parseInt($('#total1').val())+parseInt($('#total2').val())); 
                         });
```

LIVE http://jsfiddle.net/mailmerohit5/h43te3z6/